# Encountering error message when trying to load shapefile to Google Earth Engine

Tags: qgis, google-earth-engine

I have been trying to import a shapefile I have created in QGIS based on features from a boundary database I downloaded for forest conservancy boundaries in Scotland. The error message is:
Layer error: Description length exceeds maximum.
[Here is my code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/99b92d232c2fe5bb256203a8a2980542).

```
var hg = ee.FeatureCollection("users/annaelizabethk97/Highland3");


// Import my shape file of the NR
hg = hg.geometry();
Map.centerObject(hg);
Map.addLayer(hg, {color: 'red'}, 'hg');
```

I have tried reuploading everything multiple times, but always get the same message. The CRS in QGIS has been set to EPSG:27700 as it has 'performed a ballpark transform from EPSG:4326'. However, I set the CRS in the polygons that I created the shapefile with to EPSG:4326. I am very new to both Google Earth Engine and QGIS, so I have a very limited knowledge.
Could having the wrong CRS cause this error? Are there any other things I could try?

I found one other question asking about this error but they were trying to merge features
([Google Earth Engine: Layer error: Description length exceeds maximum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353072/google-earth-engine-layer-error-description-length-exceeds-maximum)).

Comment: I don't know. Could it? We can only guess when you don't provide details on the CRS you're using. Also, please include relevant code in your question, since links are subject to change. If you're link expires, the question becomes useless.

Comment: Apologies! I'm sorry- I'm very new to using these systems, and didn't think my question through properly. I have edited my question so it will hopefully be more useful. I hope that I have provided the right information now.